# TemplateDoesNotExist. loading static files and templates Django project structure

Tags: python, django

I am a bit confused on how to yield templates from other apps

Here is a picture of my project structure:

[image]

I am getting this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home.html
```

home/views.py:

```
class HomeView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "home/static/home/js"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "home/static/home/images"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "home/static/home/css"),
)


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

project/home/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from home.views import HomeView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
)
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include("home.urls", namespace="home")),

)
```

project/templates/home/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  ...
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}boothie.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom JS-->
  <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}boothie.js"></script>

  <title>Boothie</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   ...
</div>
</head>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

project/home/templates/home/home.html:

```
{% extends index.html %}

{% block content %}
    ...
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/boothie.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Unless its a typo, your template is called `home/index.html` and not `home.html`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Um I have a file called home.html within my `home` app. I guess I have bad naming convention. In my project/templates, there is a directory called home with a file `index.html`

Comment: Is it in `home/templates/home.html`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I've uploaded a picture of my project structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django stops at the first template that it finds matching the requested filename, and it will start at the `templates` directory in the app folder.

If it doesn't find it here, it will then go up the chain till it has searched all locations in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting, and only then will it print an error that it cannot find a template. The way it searches for templates is defined by the [`TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#template-loaders).

In your project layout, the template you want is located in the template directory of the home app, and inside this directory, under the `home` directory. Thus the template path should be `home/home.html` in your view:

```
class HomeView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/home.html"
```

Comment: I made some changes and added this `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/index'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home/templates/home'),
)` Not sure if this is good practice though =/

Comment: No don't do that, by default [any directory named `templates` in the app is automatically searched](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader).

Comment: Would being specific increase the search time?

Comment: You only use TEMPLATE_DIRS if you have templates that don't belong to an app. Personally, I have never found the need for this setting as all my templates live inside apps.  I really don't know what you mean "increase the search time".

Answer (score 1):

If your templates directory is in your project's root you have to add it to setitngs.py

If it's the subdirectory of an app (that is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py) then the app template loader (enabled by default) will load it.

If your app is called home then you would have the templates dir inside the home dir, not home under templates which would make it accessible as home/home.html since it's under the home subfolder of the templates dir in settings.py